# .ebextensions folder not included in my eb deploy method

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The configuration for my static files in my django project are contained in my .ebextensions folder but during the deployment process it seems the folder is not being added to the EB environment.

As a result my web app is not serving any static files when running from my ec2 instance.

I've set up environment properties to include  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles in my elastic beanstalk configuration. I've checked to ensure my .ebextensions folder exists in my github.

For some reason during deployment to EB the folder is being deleted / ignored.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? The structure of the folders of your source code ; the detail of the folder .ebextension ; the configuration of your EB environment. It's very difficult to help you with the information provided here.

Comment: also give us a log file named cfn-init.log and cfn-init-cmd.log.  They will show if container_command is actually run.